# sql server 2008 r2 express edition

Tags: sql-server

How to replicate data from sql server 2008 r2 express edition, if it is not possible then is there any third party tool for data replication from sql server 2008 r2 express edition, the matter is i want to transfer data from multiple machine from different location. those machine contain sql server 2008 r2 express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Server "Import and Export data" tool.

Comment: But Database is in different location and i want automatic replication after a certain period of time.

Comment: "Import and Export data" can work between different servers and instances. Regarding automatic replication, you might want to mention that in the question...

Comment: can It fetch data at scheduled time automatically?

Comment: Location means geographical location , data transfer via internet.

Comment: And also the data every time updated at the data base must be send to the main data base.

Comment: @user2138634: You can do data transfers over the internet using the import/export tool, but you cannot do it automatically. The express edition does not support being a replication publisher (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686(v=sql.105).aspx). You can set it up for subscription, but the publisher needs to be a full SQL Server.